# In accessing intermediate layers of keras pretrained model - error message: "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, vgg-net, keras-2

I am trying to access the output of an intermediate layer of a pretrained keras model but I am getting an exception.  My code is the following:

```
from keras.applications import vgg16
model = vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
layer_output = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = model.layers[7].output)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-1b3a5460641b> in <module>
----> 1 layer_output = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = model.layers[7].output)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    141 
    142   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 143     super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    144     _keras_api_gauge.get_cell('model').set(True)
    145 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    167         'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
    168       # Graph network
--> 169       self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
    170     else:
    171       # Subclassed network

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    454     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    455     try:
--> 456       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    457     finally:
    458       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name, **kwargs)
    273 
    274     self._base_init(name=name, **kwargs)
--> 275     self._validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs()
    276 
    277     # A Network does not create weights of its own, thus it is already

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\network.py in _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs(self)
   1350       # Check that x is an input tensor.
   1351       # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 1352       layer = x._keras_history.layer
   1353       if len(layer._inbound_nodes) > 1 or (
   1354           layer._inbound_nodes and layer._inbound_nodes[0].inbound_layers):

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
```

What creates the problem and how should I correct my code?

### Update

The problem appears at network.py file and the particular line presented in the error message is part of a function that is inside the network.py file:

```
def _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs(self):
    """Validates the inputs and outputs of a Graph Network."""
    # Check for redundancy in inputs.
    if len({id(i) for i in self.inputs}) != len(self.inputs):
      raise ValueError('The list of inputs passed to the model '
                       'is redundant. '
                       'All inputs should only appear once.'
                       ' Found: ' + str(self.inputs))

    for x in self.inputs:
      # Check that x has appropriate `_keras_history` metadata.
      if not hasattr(x, '_keras_history'):
        cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
        raise ValueError('Input tensors to a ' + cls_name + ' ' +
                         'must come from `tf.keras.Input`. '
                         'Received: ' + str(x) +
                         ' (missing previous layer metadata).')
      # Check that x is an input tensor.
      # pylint: disable=protected-access
      layer = x._keras_history.layer
      if len(layer._inbound_nodes) > 1 or (
          layer._inbound_nodes and layer._inbound_nodes[0].inbound_layers):
        cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
        logging.warning(cls_name + ' inputs must come from '
                        '`tf.keras.Input` (thus holding past layer metadata), '
                        'they cannot be the output of '
                        'a previous non-Input layer. '
                        'Here, a tensor specified as '
                        'input to "' + self.name + '" was not an Input tensor, '
                        'it was generated by layer ' + layer.name + '.\n'
                        'Note that input tensors are '
                        'instantiated via `tensor = tf.keras.Input(shape)`.\n'
                        'The tensor that caused the issue was: ' + str(x.name))
      if isinstance(x, ragged_tensor.RaggedTensor):
        self._supports_ragged_inputs = True

    # Check compatibility of batch sizes of Input Layers.
    input_batch_sizes = [
        training_utils.get_static_batch_size(x._keras_history.layer)
        for x in self.inputs
    ]
    consistent_batch_size = None
    for batch_size in input_batch_sizes:
      if batch_size is not None:
        if (consistent_batch_size is not None and
            batch_size != consistent_batch_size):
          raise ValueError('The specified batch sizes of the Input Layers'
                           ' are incompatible. Found batch sizes: {}'.format(
                               input_batch_sizes))
        consistent_batch_size = batch_size

    for x in self.outputs:
      if not hasattr(x, '_keras_history'):
        cls_name = self.__class__.__name__
        raise ValueError('Output tensors to a ' + cls_name + ' must be '
                         'the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` '
                         '(thus holding past layer metadata). Found: ' + str(x))
```

x is an attribute of the Class Network defined in the same network.py file as follows:

````
class Network(base_layer.Layer):
  """A `Network` is a composition of layers.

  `Network` is the topological form of a "model". A `Model`
  is simply a `Network` with added training routines.

  Two types of `Networks` exist: Graph Networks and Subclass Networks. Graph
  networks are used in the Keras Functional and Sequential APIs. Subclassed
  networks are used when a user subclasses the `Model` class. In general,
  more Keras features are supported with Graph Networks than with Subclassed
  Networks, specifically:

  - Model cloning (`keras.models.clone`)
  - Serialization (`model.get_config()/from_config`, `model.to_json()/to_yaml()`
  - Whole-model saving (`model.save()`)

  A Graph Network can be instantiated by passing two arguments to `__init__`.
  The first argument is the `keras.Input` Tensors that represent the inputs
  to the Network. The second argument specifies the output Tensors that
  represent the outputs of this Network. Both arguments can be a nested
  structure of Tensors.

  Example:

  ```
  inputs = {'x1': keras.Input(shape=(10,)), 'x2': keras.Input(shape=(1,))}
  t = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(inputs['x1'])
  outputs = keras.layers.Add()([t, inputs['x2'])
  network = Network(inputs, outputs)
  ```

  A Graph Network constructed using the Functional API can also include raw
  TensorFlow functions, with the exception of functions that create Variables
  or assign ops.

  Example:

  ```
  inputs = keras.Input(shape=(10,))
  x = keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
  outputs = tf.nn.relu(x)
  network = Network(inputs, outputs)
  ```

  Subclassed Networks can be instantiated via `name` and (optional) `dynamic`
  keyword arguments. Subclassed Networks keep track of their Layers, and their
  `call` method can be overridden. Subclassed Networks are typically created
  indirectly, by subclassing the `Model` class.

  Example:

  ```
  class MyModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
      super(MyModel, self).__init__(name='my_model', dynamic=False)

      self.layer1 = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')

    def call(self, inputs):
      return self.layer1(inputs)
  ```

  Allowed args in `super().__init__`:
    name: String name of the model.
    dynamic: (Subclassed models only) Set this to `True` if your model should
      only be run eagerly, and should not be used to generate a static
      computation graph. This attribute is automatically set for Functional API
      models.
    trainable: Boolean, whether the model's variables should be trainable.
    dtype: (Subclassed models only) Default dtype of the model's weights (
      default of `None` means use the type of the first input). This attribute
      has no effect on Functional API models, which do not have weights of their
      own.
  """

  # See tf.Module for the usage of this property.
  # The key of _layer_call_argspecs is a layer. tf.Module._flatten will fail to
  # flatten the key since it is trying to convert Trackable/Layer to a string.
  _TF_MODULE_IGNORED_PROPERTIES = frozenset(itertools.chain(
      ('_layer_call_argspecs', '_compiled_trainable_state'),
      base_layer.Layer._TF_MODULE_IGNORED_PROPERTIES
  ))
````

Comment: Hi, I ran ur code above in colab, I'm not getting any errors

Comment: @Aditya Mishra So the code is correct, but still, I am having this problem. Any ideas on how to debug it?

Comment: Which version of keras are you using? Did you try this on your local setup or some other cloud service? Also, if you are willing you could take a look at the file the traceback points to `network.py`. It really intrigues me what `x` is there on line 1352

Comment: @Aditya Mishra:  Thank you for the suggestion.  I am using keras 2, tensorflow 2 in my system.  The problem appearing in the network.py file relates to a particular function in this file, which code I have included in my updated post.  If I understand well checks if the tensor x is an input tensor.  x is an attribute of the Class Network defined in the same network.py file -- I have also included the code.